# Template Error when Deployed using TDS

Tags: tds

I have created a new template on my local machine. The template is working fine on the local machine.
I have synced the file in the TDS project, where the deployment strategy for all items of the template is `always update` and `keep all child items synchronized`.

When I build the TDS project and Deploy it on the test server. After deployment is complete, I am getting the error
[image]

I am not sure what could be causing this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

There is 1 section and 2 fields in the template, 1 field is single-line text field and another field is a Droplink.

I can still open the section item and field items from the content tree which seem to be fine. Also, if I happen to duplicate this template, then the new template works fine without the error mentioned above.

Please let me know if you need any more details or the template structure around it.

Comment: Try deleting the item(s) and redeploying.

Comment: Done that multiple times. Didn't work.

Comment: You may hav a missing inherited template from somewhere else. You can also try deleting the items from TDS and then re-adding them and redeploying.

Comment: I think this could be related to Solr maybe, I have 3 QA environments. It got correctly build on 2 of them but not on the 3rd one. The templates were not building fine in 2 of them till yesterday. Redeploying resolved issue in 1 of them. Now, I have created a package of template from the one where it got deployed correctly and tried to install that package on the environment where it is not working and I was not able to install the template. The template is not inherited by any template expect for standard template.